# Golang/ReactJS CORS trouble

Tags: javascript, reactjs, go, cors, mux

Facing this error in console when I try to send a post request with axios

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

```
axios.post('localhost:8080', { username }).then(res => {
    // Do stuff
  })
```

There seem to be a few methods for handling this, but none of them seem to be working for me. For example, this does not work:

```
func main() {

    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.HandleFunc("/username", models.CheckUsername).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")

    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    })

    handler := c.Handler(router)

    log.Println("Listening on port ", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(port, handler))
}
```

Comment: `AllowedOrigins` should be `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Try also `axios.post('http://localhost:8080', ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change AllowedOrigins: value from http://localhost:8080 to http://localhost:3000

Comment: Tried this and same effect. Edited the question.

Comment: which package do you use for cors? https://github.com/rs/cors ?

Comment: Yes, that's the one

Comment: Got it working. Going to accept this because this was a part of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Cody what was the rest of the problem? I'm facing the same issue